# IIS Multiple sites bindings and hosts configuration

Tags: iis, binding, iis-7.5, hosts

I am trying to configure multiple websites to run on the same server running IIS 7.5.  However, I am having issues accessing the second website from a computer on the network but I don't know what should be the correct configuration.

The default website works both locally and remotely. I.e. if I type in localhost on the server then it will work and if I type in the server's ip address from another computer it will also work.

It has the following bindings settings:

```
- IP address: All unassigned 
- Port: 80
- Host name: blank
```

However, the second website (called "testapp") only works locally.  I.e. I can access it when I am on the server by typing in it's binding host name but when I try to access it by from another computer by typing in "ip address/TestApp/". It returns a 404 - file or directory not found error.

It has the following settings:

```
- IP address: All unassigned 
- Port: 80
- Host name: testapp
```

and an entry in the hosts file

```
- 127.0.0.1     testapp
```

I know i am probably just missing something simple but anything help would be appreciated!

Comment: https://www.jexusmanager.com/en/latest/tutorials/binding-diagnostics.html Use Jexus Manager to learn the bindings, and then the answer would be clear.

Answer (score 1):

`"ip address/TestApp/"` will be sending the traffic to the default website (it will also do this from the server hosting `TestApp`). You need to setup DNS so your clients can use the hostname to resolve the IP or add a hostfile on *each* computer that connects if you dont have a DNS service for named bindings to work as you expect.

"Under-the-hood" when a browser sends an HTTP request (ie typing a url/clicking a link), the domain name is sent in the `HOST` HTTP header, this header is used by IIS to determine which site (ie binding) traffic is sent. When using the IP, your not providing a hostname, so no `HOST` header is sent, so IIS will route traffic to the default site (ie binding without a hostname specified).

You can see this in action by firing up Telnet, and issuing an HTTP request to your servers IP address (from localhost or another host) and include the HOST header you should get the expected response. (This isnt terribly useful - this is normally done by your browser - but it might give you some insight into whats really happening...)

Start Telnet with `telnet 192.168.1.2 80"` (change the IP for your server), then copy/paste or type the below 2 lines into the telnet window, then a blank line:

```
GET /TestApp/ HTTP/1.1
host: testapp
```

You should see the HTML returned from that URL. If you try the above, but omit the `host`, you will get the HTML from the default website (or the 404 page etc)